# Docker compose. Networks. Spring Boot and MySQL connection

Tags: mysql, spring, docker, docker-compose

I try to connect spring boot web app to database container.
And I can ping db container from web. But web can't connect to db by exposed 3307 port. But I can connect to db by internal container port 3306. Project very simple. What is may wrong?

This is my **docker-compose.yml**:

```
    version: '3'
services:
  db:
    build:
      context: ./db
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: db
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - demo_volume:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - my-backend

  web:
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: web
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "18080:8080"
    networks:
      - my-backend
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - DATABASE_USER=user
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
      - DATABASE_NAME=demo
      - DATABASE_PORT=3307
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=container
      - DEBUG=true

volumes:
  demo_volume:
    driver: local

networks:
  my-backend:
    driver: bridge
```

It's simple enough.

My **application.yml** for active profile - **container**

```
spring:
  profiles:
    container
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://${DATABASE_HOST}:${DATABASE_PORT}/${DATABASE_NAME}?characterEncoding=UTF-8
    username: ${DATABASE_USER}
    password: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Also very simple

**db Dockerfile**:

```
FROM mysql:5.7

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=demo
ENV MYSQL_USER=user
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=password

ADD dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

And **web Dockerfile**:

```
FROM java:8-jre
COPY ./web.jar /app/web.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/web.jar"]
CMD ["java", "-Xmx200m", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "/app/web.jar"]
```

Comment: **dcoker version**
`Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Tue Mar 28 00:40:02 2017
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Fri Mar 24 00:00:50 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
`

Comment: what's the output for `iptables -t nat -L -n`?

Comment: @AlexKarshin iptables: command not found

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Docker documentation all containers in the same bridge network (user defined) communicates via their internal ports. It's explained with image [isolated_bridge_network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgGq5.png)

If you desire your containers should be available from external network you should **publish** ports for this one. Publish - means you should map internal ports to external environment. See on image 
[published_ports_from_isolated_bridge_network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xYYE.png)

Answer (score -2):

You should link the Container to make it work.

```
web:
build:
  context: ./web
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
image: web
depends_on:
  - db
ports:
  - "18080:8080"
networks:
  - my-backend
environment:
  - DATABASE_HOST=db
  - DATABASE_USER=user
  - DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
  - DATABASE_NAME=demo
  - DATABASE_PORT=3307
  - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=container
  - DEBUG=true
links:
  - db
```

Now inside your web Container /etc/hosts should have an entry for db Container

Comment: I'm sorry but I should not. **link** is deprecated statement